# mac: simplest way to safely serve a django app on port 80 for development

Tags: django, macos, security

I'd like to open up my django app to other machines in the office during development.
I understand that it's a bad idea to run the django development server as root. The recommended way to serve a django app on port 80, even during development, appears to be django, plus gunicorn, plus nginx. This seems super complicated to me. I got the first two steps working, but am now staring at nginx in utter confusion. There's no mac build on the site. Do I really have to build it from the source?

One alternative I've come across is [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/). But this seems sketchy to me, and involves setting up public keys and whatnot. Is there any simpler way to serve a django app on a mac from port 80 without running it as root?

Also, just what are the risks of running a django development server on port 80 as root, vs not as root? What are the chances that someone could, say, gain total access to my file system? And, given the default user settings on a mac, is this more likely if I'm running my django dev server as root than if I'm running it as not-root?

Comment: Why don't you just `./manage.py runserver your.lan.ip.address:80`? Unless your machine is reachable from the Internet you are safe.

Comment: Or just do ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: What Paulo Scardine and dan-klasson says requires to run as root... instead you can do `./manage.py runserver` (as normal) and then create a reverse proxy in apache (if nginx is complicated for you) just setting `ProxyPass` on a virtualhost... something like this would work:

`<Location />
ProxyPass http://localhost:8000/
</Location>`

Comment: @PauloScardine "Unless your machine is reachable from the Internet". I'm embarrassed to say I don't entirely understand what determines whether or not my machine is reachable from the internet.

Comment: @morgancodes: in a corporate network you are probably behind a firewall/gateway and using an IP address reserved for internal networks - these are not reachable from Internet without extra configuration of the firewall/gateway. Usually they start with `192.169.0.*`, `172.16.*.*` or `10.*.*.*`. Ask the network administrator to be sure, but if your LAN address is like these most likely you are safe from some random internet dude poking your test server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned you don't want to run the Django server as root and you are on a mac, you could forward traffic from port 80 to port 8000:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8000 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

and then run the Django server as a normal user (by default it serves on port 8000)

```
./manage.py runserver
```

To remove the port forwarding, run:

```
sudo ipfw flush
```